# Literature request -- uniqueness and existence of a specific type of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, random-functions

I am looking for a proof of the existence and uniquenes of ODE's of the type:

\begin{equation}
                            \dot{f}(t,x,y) = F(h(t,x), f(t,x,y)), 
\end{equation}

where $f : T \times X \times Y \rightarrow Y, h : T \times X \rightarrow X$ and $F : X \times Y \rightarrow Y$, i.e. a pathwise random differential equation:

\begin{equation}
\dot{f}_t = F(h_t (x), f_t).
\end{equation}
My motivation is the study of random dynamical systems (RDS), which is generated by equations of the type

\begin{equation}
\dot{\phi}(t, \omega, x) = f(\theta (t, \omega), \phi (t, \omega, x)),
\end{equation}

where $\phi : T \times \Omega \times X \rightarrow X$ and $\theta : T \times \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$, for $T$ some semigroup, $X$ a (measurable/topological) space and $\Omega$ a probability space.

These are treated in the seminal book on RDS by L. Arnold (chapter 2), but he refers to a rather obscure, German 1983 paper for the existence & uniqueness part.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: L. Arnold refers not to a paper but to one the best references that you can find for the fundamental theory of differential equations, the extraordinary book by Amann (with an English translation since 1990). As Arnold details: "The existence, uniqueness and regularity proofs are $\omega$-wise adaptations of the deterministic proofs". This means that you can safely say that all is the same as in the usual theory, up to the need of keeping track of the extra $\omega$.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you :D